# SSRS Link Chart With Matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, matrix, charts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart and a matrix on the same report. The matrix has the ability to toggle. When collapsed the matrix shows the SalesTerritory and it's sales amount eg North America. When it is expanded it shows the Countries and their sale amount.

```
ex
   North America      25
        USA           10
        Canada        15
   Europe             45
```

I have this correctly working, but somehow I have to link the chart with the table below. If nothing is expanded the chart should display the territories and their sales amounts, but as soon as I expand a group the chart should change and display the counties and their sales amount. I've looked and looked and I can't seem to find anything on how to accomplish this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably filtering the chart data is the only way. Is possible for limited states.

Comment: This cannot be done, not without re-running the report. Charts in SSRS are images of the chart rendered at runtime. They CAN have links to other reports etc using Actions, but they CANNOT be interactive in any  other way. Once drawn that is how the chart looks.

Answer (score 0):

I said in my comment to your original post that this cannot be done... sort of.

You can't change a chart once rendered, but the method in the link below creates many charts which you can show or hide with the columns:

http://www.sqljason.com/2012/10/ssrs-charts-with-data-tables-excel-style.html

You'd have to have the chart side-by-side with your data, though. Or turn your data on its side and have the chart directly above or below.